# Sql to get data whose expiry date is coming close

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called "Listings" as below :

```
Id      RealEstateAgentId       DepartmentId    Status      CityId      ProvinceId      CountryId       
ListingPostedDate           ListingExpirydate
```

`Status` column can have these values:

- 1 - Active
- 2 - Sold
- 3 - Expired

Now, I want to get top 10 active listings having the closest expiry date by sorting by number of days left, from lowest to highest. If the expiry date of more than 1 listings are the same, then we will sort according to the `Id` primary column (from lowest to highest).

But I am not getting the logic for the closest expiry date.

For example: if it would have been to find the listings whose expiry date is in 2 months then something like below should be fine :

```
select * 
from Listings 
where ListingExpirydate < dateadd(month, 2, getdate());
```

Can someone help me with idea or logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> closest Expiry Date

for this, we should check the current date with `ListingExpirydate` column to get closet expiring records

```
DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), l.ListingExpirydate)
```

for Top 10 and active record applied these filters to query:

```
select top(10) l.*
...
where status= 1
```

and final code is below:

```
 select top(10) l.*, 
        DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), l.ListingExpirydate) daysLeftToExpire 
 from Listings l
 where status= 1
 order by DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), l.ListingExpirydate) , id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but 'daysLeftToExpire' returns value value in negative.

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I want to get top 10 Active Listings

```
SELECT TOP(10)

WHERE status = 1
```

> having the closest Expiry Date by sorting by number of days left, from lowest to highest. If the Expiry Date of more than 1 listings are the same, then we will sort according to the "Id" primary column (from lowest to highest).

```
ORDER BY listingexpirydate, id
```

The complete query:

```
select top(10) *
from listings 
where status = 1
order by listingexpirydate, id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can you tell me how do I calculate number of days left in listing going to expire?

Comment: In SQL Server use `DATEDIFF` for this. `GETDATE()` gets you the current date to compare with. Combined: `DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), listingexpirydate,)`. Docs: [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [GETDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: And surely you want to filter for "current" rows using something like `WHERE listingexpirydate > GETDATE()`

Comment: @SMor: I assume that rows with the status Active opposed to Expired or Sold are the current ones. (I admit this doesn't look good, because status and expiry date are obviously redundant - if the expiry date is in the past, how could the row be Active and not Expired?)